# WPF Error: Could not create an instance of type... when creating custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a custom Tag Cloud control. The way it's supposed to work is that the user can give it a collection of strings in the itemsSource and the converted string will be displayed in the UI. The problem is when I try to drop the control into an application I get the following error:"Could not create an instance of type TagCloudControl". Can anyone help?

**Code behind**

```
public class TagCloudControl : ListBox
{
    static TagCloudControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TagCloudControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            (typeof(TagCloudControl)));
    }
    //tags dependency property
    public static DependencyProperty TagsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Tags",
        typeof(IEnumerable<Tag>),
        typeof(TagCloudControl));

    public CollectionView GroupedTagsView { get; set; }

    public TagCloudControl()
    {
        ItemsSource = Tags;

        //group my tags by "name" property
        GroupedTagsView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Tags);
        GroupedTagsView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name")); 

    }

    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<Tag>)GetValue(TagsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TagsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="TagCloudDemo.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:TagCloudControlLibrary;assembly=TagCloudControlLibrary"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>

    <src:TagCloudControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="firstTag"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

**TagControl xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TagCloudControlLibrary">

<local:CountToBrushConverter x:Key="CountToBrushConverter"/>
<local:CountToFontSizeConverter x:Key="CountToFontSizeConverter"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TagCloudControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TagCloudControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                               Margin="2"
                               IsItemsHost="True">
                    </WrapPanel>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TagsTemplate">
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                   FontSize="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToBrushConverter}}"
                   Foreground="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}}"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Tag Class**

```
public class Tag
{
    public Tag(string name)
    {
        Name = name;        
    }

    public string Name { get; set;}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to instantiate Tags?

I'm guessing it's a null reference exception, you set your items source as Tags in your constructor, but you have not instantiated Tags.

```
public TagCloudControl()
{
    Tags = new ObservableCollection<Tags>();

    ItemsSource = Tags;
    ...
}
```

Edit:

After playing around with code... I'm thinking that Tags might not need to be a DependencyProperty. It appears you want to Bind the ItemsSource to Tags... but you could just make Tags a simple property, and in it, set the ItemsSource to the value passed in:

```
public TagCloudControl()
{
    //this is now empty.
} 

public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags
{
    get { return (this.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<Tag>); }
    set { this.ItemsSource = value; }
}
```

Also I think your Style might want to be more like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TagCloudControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tag}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontSize="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToBrushConverter}}"
                           Foreground="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}}">
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TagCloudControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True">
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And finally, I think you might be missing ItemCount in your 'Tag' Class.

Comment: Thanks, I got the error "a new expression requires () after type"

Comment: Yeah... I forgot the ()... I edited to update. (Also, you'll want to remove the '**'s as well). And it can't be just IEnumerable. It'd have to be a specific Type that implements IEnumerable.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will mark as answer, In terms of my logic does this look ok?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure what's going on with the private static constructor and a public constructor, but assuming that's not the problem. You don't appear to be setting your Tags Dependency property in the xaml...

Comment: I'm going to mock something up quick to test it all out and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Everything seems to be working so far. Can you provide your TagCloudControl xaml, and your Tag class?

Comment: Aha... I think the problem is you need to Bind ItemSource to Tags not set it to Tags...

Comment: Oh I see, how do I do this? And did it work for you after that?

Comment: See my updated code. I think I found a simpler solution for you. I struggled with finding an easy way to do the binding. I used my solution above (I didn't use the converters as I didn't see an ItemCount property to bind to) and it all seemed to work. In code I created an ObservableCollection<Tag> tagList and added two Tags to it. I then set firstTag.Tags = tagList in code and my two tags were displayed!